# How I know if CPU is Haswell or Not

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-5.0

You know, **haswell** is the codename for a processor microarchitecture developed by Intel as the "fourth-generation core" successor to the Ivy Bridge microarchitecture.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haswell_(microarchitecture)) Intel officially announced CPUs based on this microarchitecture... [More](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haswell_(microarchitecture))

**But**, I want to know how to show's up my CPU if haswell or not by using the **PowerShell** in windows?
in this case i have a script to to that, but it maybe not legal for everyone:

```
$cpuname = (Get-CimInstance CIM_Processor).Name
$splcpuall = @($cpuname -csplit "")
$splcpu = $splcpuall[20]

$ishaswell = if ($splcpu -gt 3){
    Write-Output "Haswell"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Identifying a CPU needs some digging and regular maintenance for new CPU models is needed too. Your best bet is to use some existing tool that provides CPU information. For example, CPU-Z is nice a tool.

The problem is that CPUs don't contain human readable name strings. What they contain is a CPUID, a hex code that must be looked up and interpreted as model name. Hashwell's ID is `0x0306C3`, Broadwell's is `0x0306D4` and so on.

Digging up the CPUID can be done via WMI. On a Broadwell box:

```
(gwmi win32_processor).ProcessorId
BFEBFBFF000306D4
```

The result is a [string combination](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394373(v=vs.85).aspx) that contains stuff in addition to the CPU ID. This needs to be parsed to identify the CPU ID part and then the matched name must be looked up from somewhere.

Comment: thank you to getting me some idea to do that. is this problim?

$laststr = [string] (gwmi win32_processor).ProcessorId
$isHaswell = if($laststr -match "306C3"){
    Write-Output "Haswell"
}elseif($laststr -notmatch "306C3"){
    Write-Output "Broadwell"
}else{
    Write-Output "Something Else!"
}

Comment: @Aso Why are you interested if the CPU is a Haswell anyway? Are you actually interested if the CPU has support for, say, VT-x?

Comment: In fact I want to create a PowerShell tool, which has a many difference parts to getting system information.